# Python - function should return a 2D list

Tags: python

I'm given a lambda function and a 2D list. It must be done with `reduce()`.  Let's say:

```
func=lambda x,y:x+y
input=[[2,3],[4,5]]
# OUTPUT should be [[5],[9]]
```

All I got is:

```
arr=[]
arr.append(reduce (lambda x,y:x+y,[i for i in input[0]]))
arr.append(reduce (lambda x,y:x+y,[i for i in input[1]]))
return arr
# OUTPUT here is [5,9]
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: `[i for i in whatever]` is just a copy of `whatever`.

Comment: Are the sublists in `input` guaranteed to have just 2 elements, or can each one have an arbitrary length, for example, `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6, 7], [8,9]]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
[reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, item) for item in input]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just surround the call to `reduce` with `[...]`.

Example: `arr.append([reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,input[0]]))`

Also, there's no need to use a comprehension in the call to `reduce`, as I have shown in the example above.

Finally, as @Roman Kh pointed out, this can all be compressed into one statement: `arr = [reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, item) for item in input]`